# Capturing superfluid condensation with exact diagonalization

Tags: many-body, bosons, superfluidity, computational-physics

Doing exact diagonalization on bosonic systems is tricky, because the possibility of multiple occupancy means that even the single-site Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional.  It's my understanding that in practice, people just truncate the single-site Hilbert space to a small size, perhaps with some hand-wavy assumption that the bosons repel strongly enough that multiple occupancy is suppressed.  But then how can you detect the onset of superfluidity, in which the ground state becomes a phase-coherent state that is a linear combination of all possible bosonic occupation numbers, even arbitrarily high ones?  Do you just have to tune the chemical potential so that the superfluid density isn't too high, and then just hope for the best that the density fluctuations will be reasonably small?